# Python dictionary very slow(2-D hash table)

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I want to use a 2-D array as a hash table, in C, it's like:

`hash[1][2] = 1`

and in Python, I tried:

```
hash = {}
hash[1,2] = 1
```

But it turns out to be **very slow**.

So how to implement a 2-D hash table efficiently in Python?

**Update:**

My program is a computing heavy one. Since Python dict allocates memory dynamically, I can see that the program is waiting for memory allocation in the run time, while the CPU usage is sometimes low, sometimes high.

A C-style 2-D array should be OK but I don't know how to implement it in Python.

Comment: Define "very slow". A tuple is a perfectly fine key as long as you do not need to iterate over just a part of it.

Comment: Python's dicts are the fastest hash table possible in Python, because they are implemented in C.  Provide *lots* more details about your code and your performance problem.

Comment: @ThiefMaster "very slow" means when I run the program(a computing heavy one), the CPU usage is low and I can see that the program is waiting for memory allocation. the tuple supports something like:`t = ();t[1,2]=1`?

Comment: can.: update the question with more details: how many keys are you creating, are the values really just integers, or something else?  What kind of algorithm are you using?  What is the mix of reads to writes? Why aren't you just using a 2D array? Is it sparse?  All of these details will help to get the right answer.

Comment: @NedBatchelder a C-style 2D array should be OK, I just don't know how to implement it in Python

Comment: @can.:The program is a computation heavy one but the CPU usage is low? Seems like a contradiction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is fine or not depends on your use-case. If you want something like `hash[1][2]`, i.e. so you can iterate over `hash[x]` without ever touching the other `hash[y]` elements the tuple key is *not* a good solution. In this case you better do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
hash = defaultdict(dict)
hash[1][2] = 1
```

This makes `hash` a dict containing other dicts instad of a single dict with a composite (tuple) key. Using the `defaultdict` is mainly sugar to avoid `hash.setdefault(1, {})` calls to create subdicts in case they don't exist yet.

Comment: also note also that every call to `has.setdefault(1,{})` creates that empty dict in the second argument on the off-chance that it would be needed - defaultdict doesn't need to do this, since it is created with a factory function and so only creates new elements if they are needed to initialize an entry for a new key.

Answer (score 1):

What you did 1 level dict with compound key:

```
arr = { (1,2): "a", (1,3): "b" }
```

Another alternative is 2-level dict:

```
arr = { 1: { 2: "a", 3: "b" }}
```

Yet another is to use e.g. numpy.array(), IIRC it cannot be sparse.

scipy has sparse marix class that can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to C if you follow the code below:

```
a={}
a[1]={}
a[2]={}
```

Now 'a' is a dictionary of dictionaries simulating your use-case.
Now you can use it as:

```
a[1][1] = anyVal;
a[1][2] = otherVal;
a[2][1] = anotherVal;
```

etc,etc...

Answer (score 0):

If the set of possible keys is small, you could also use a list of lists. Here is a very simple-minded Markov generator using pairs of characters from an input corpus to create new "sentences". Note the initialization of the list-of-lists `markov_pairs`, which is how you would get a 2D array using Python lists.

```
import random
import string
all_letters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase

corpus = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
            labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
            eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""
# normalize all spaces to single spaces
corpus = ' '.join(corpus.split())

# initialize 2-D array for sequence tally
markov_pairs = [[0]*256 for i in range(256)]

# make sure every letter and space has at least *some* probability of following
# any other letter
for sublist in markov_pairs:
    for i in range(len(sublist)):
        if chr(i) in all_letters+' ':
            sublist[i] += 1

# pairwise iterate over input corpus, updating markov pairs with observed pairs
it = iter(corpus)
last = next(it)
for c in it:
    markov_pairs[ord(last)][ord(c)] += 10000
    last = c

# function to guess a next character, given a starting character, based on the
# frequencies found in the input corpus
def getNext(pairs, from_):
    probs = pairs[ord(from_)]
    num = random.randint(0,sum(probs))
    # reorder probs so highest weights are up front
    for p,c in sorted(((p,chr(i)) for i,p in enumerate(probs) if p),reverse=True):
        num -= p
        if num <= 0: break
    return c

# generate some new text based on the corpus
for i in range(20):
    ret = []
    last = random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    while last in (all_letters+' '):
        ret.append(last)
        last = getNext(markov_pairs, last)
    print ''.join(ret)
```

Prints (sort of a mix of Latin and Tourette's Syndrome):

```
NEx quite eria nalorunorein ulag Utalidor eniqum atet
SPllalalad nsiqudont intret
RCve ollat rim don epored lonidolid im cuatempt esepiaent furiutautr lit m vehenise vex nst
Wveta cet at mp icur e co anorepit pidomodor ng ala
Lorurim
Fm dorisseiuimondedor nid lunor
HJcupter Excarcuro don itaboffuitese cosensest emm cim e ct vonut s cosudodisir
Habocinim issit nia iat uininolla iatere e a aulict catenipa pont
Sgiteps a t cor
PRRfinsmabommo dupagnit norer olulaboi mipit
Exearicat ites e ngn ptrequmpa n uiuia imema cuause dont
Ex inod in amost met
Ae s cutes ia
CKx fint m e cor olllulalicun sedoreuipa ciuam
Oorolatrenor cum a is d Dum e edocipit m cimont eum lliofinsit aret am elorellisterexereminidit elolititresuntexelimomp poisudinisenorute a abolor ex ont
BZt ret taenorenat miqururcon Duit sea ca vexexeserurisulollat
Tlit aboceda qupriut m cualllupip cad d s dect
Ohet em uidid iam it d edollat a ssicaruir idor d unon n e e colaum funsiabontiataboressusia ffise Dum vororeruisedor redeit aupos cat epom ipt
GDust
Hyalorunofit d qur enser
```